# Get the csv header as a string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header

That's my code

```
cabecalho = pd.read_csv('2992.csv', sep ='|', encoding = 'latin-1', header = [0, 1], nrows = 0)
```

It should be like this:

```
JOB - 2992 - Listão Telefonia - GO/MG/BA - VIVO/CLARO/TIM/OI
Veiculação: 23/09/2019 - Validade: 23/09/2019 até 29/09/2019
```

I want to save it as a string to use as a title for my html file, so I'm trying this:

```
cabecalho.to_string()

'Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [(JOB - 2992 - Listão Telefonia - GO/MG/BA - VIVO/CLARO/TIM/OI, Veiculação: 23/09/2019 - Validade: 23/09/2019 até 29/09/2019)]\nIndex: []'
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `I want to save it as a string to use as a title for my html file` - can you post the complete intended output?

Comment: You probably want to include first few lines of your `csv`.

Comment: But I don't want to show the lines, only the header

Comment: I don't want to show   
`'Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [(JOB - 2992 - Listão Telefonia - GO/MG/BA - VIVO/CLARO/TIM/OI, Veiculação: 23/09/2019 - Validade: 23/09/2019 até 29/09/2019)]\nIndex: []'`   

I need   
`JOB - 2992 - Listão Telefonia - GO/MG/BA - VIVO/CLARO/TIM/OI Veiculação: 23/09/2019 - Validade: 23/09/2019 até 29/09/2019`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in cabecalho.columns])`

This will convert columns to string separated by `space`

Comment: `"('JOB - 2992 - Listão Telefonia - GO/MG/BA - VIVO/CLARO/TIM/OI', 'Veiculação: 23/09/2019 - Validade: 23/09/2019 até 29/09/2019')"`

Comment: Now I have to replace some characters but this is ok...which method can i use to do this?

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking here but to replace some characters from string, lookup `string.replace()` python function

Comment: what is the output of just `cabecalho.columns`?